# Is it possible to assign the hash(#) automatically in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, typescript

Is there any way where I can assign the hash(#) automatically to the elements inside an ngfor?

```
<div *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
      <h3 #[note][i]>
        {{ note }}
      </h3>
</div>
```

The result I would expect would be something like this:

```
<div>
      <h3 #note11>
        note1
      </h3>
</div>
<div>
      <h3 #note122>
        note12
      </h3>
</div>
<div>
      <h3 #note153>
        note15
      </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand anything... What you wanna do?

Comment: Thats not possible. Dynamic created hashed names (variable declaration) is not possible. Use properties or directives instead.

Comment: Not, but you really needn't do it in any case. Inside the `*ngFor` [template variables are scoped](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope) In ts you can get it using [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). What are you try to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index variable to automatically assign a unique id to each element in the ngFor loop. Here's an example:

```
  <div *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
      <h3 id="note{{i}}">
        {{ note }}
      </h3>
</div>
```

This will give each element an id of "note0", "note1", "note2", etc.

Regarding using #, it is not possible to use it in such a way. The # symbol is used to create a template reference variable, you can use it like <h3 #myNote>{{ note }} and you can access the element using myNote in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let note of notes; index as i">
  <h3 #{{note}}{{i}}>
    {{ note }}
  </h3>
</div>
```

Note:
This would do your work but # is used to create template reference.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.